# P-test for Convergence

Tags: integration

Determine whether the integral converges or diverges. $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\root\of{x^7+14}}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\root\of{x^7+14}}dx\approx\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{\root\of{x^7}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1.5}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{1.5}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1.5}}dx$$

The integral on the left diverges by the p-test as $0<x<1$, but the integral on the right converges. Therefore, the integral must be divergent.

However, this integral is convergent. How is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Notice that we have

$$\left|\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^7+14}}\,dx\right|\le \frac1{\sqrt{14}}\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$$

and

$$\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^7+14}}\,dx\right|\le \int_1^\infty x^{-3/2}\,dx$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure I understand. Can you be a little bit more explicit?

Comment: You're welcome.  Split the integral as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^7+14}}\,dx=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^7+14}}\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^7+14}}\,dx$$Then apply the inequalities in the answer and verify that the integral of interest does indeed converge.